# Java - map key lookup ignoring case

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, string-comparison

I'm writing a script that creates a map from user nicknames to user IDs:

```
// Get client informations to map
for (Client c : api.getClients()) {
  teamspeakUserInfos.put(c.getNickname(), c.getId());
}
```

Example mapping:

```
Nickname | 5
Username | 2
John     |12
```

Here is my code for checking key presence in the map:

```
if (teamspeakUserInfos.containsKey(genUserNickname())) {
  victimTeamspeakID = teamspeakUserInfos.get(genUserNickname());
  break;
}
```

`genUserNickname()` can return upper-, lower- or mixed-case nickname.

My question now is, how can I check if this nickname is used as a key - while ignoring case differences?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: it would better to include that in the post.

Comment: What is a "character size"?

Comment: Can you just store the nickname in the map as uppercase, and use `teamspeakUserInfos.containsKey(getUserNickname().toUpperCase())`?

Comment: I suspect the answer you are looking for is to use `.put(c.getNickname().toLowercase(), ...)`, and then use `containsKey(genUserNickname(). toLowercase())` etc to retrieve from the map.

Comment: @DaveDrake Sure, but I have to access them sometime and then it would be better if the writing is correct.

Comment: @AndyTurner That was wrong wording. I meant upper and lower case of the individual letters.

`.toLowerCase()` 

unfortunately doesn't work ... theoretically this command only sets the searched string small but the comparison should only check the content of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something similar:

```
public class ContainsKeyIgnoreCase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, Integer> userInfo = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        userInfo.put("nickNamE", 1);

        String nickName = "NiCKname";

        System.out.println(containsKeyIgnoreCase(userInfo, nickName));
    }

    public static boolean containsKeyIgnoreCase(Map<String, Integer> map, String lookupKey) {
        return map.keySet()
                  .stream()
                  .map(key -> key.equalsIgnoreCase(lookupKey))
                  .reduce(false, Boolean::logicalOr);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you fast replay!

`Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> map(Function<? super T,? extends 
 R>)`

Comment: @snorp I have added a complete code example to my answer, it worked for me (`true`is printed in the console). Your problem could be an Eclipse bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42285370/cannot-infer-type-arguments-for-r-mapfunction-super-t-extends-r-in-so

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice! I am currently using Version 4.9.0 of Eclipse and the bug was fixed with release 4.6.3 so I do not know why I still get this Error.

EDIT: I will test your edited example above...
EDIT2: It works like a charm, thank you very much. Now I get an error because of the string genUserNickname.

`Local variable genUserNickname defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final`

But the whole thing is in a while loop. Anyway the problem I had first is solved thank you very much!